# Gunicorn 'ImportError: No module named app.wsgiapp' on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, wsgi, gunicorn

I cannot run gunicorn on heroku with simple flask app.
The application is really simple. This is app.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def say_hello(url):
    return "Hello"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8888))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=port)
```

The app works fine through flask test server on heroku, but
when I switch to use gunicorn, it crashes with:

```
ImportError: No module named app.wsgiapp
```

My requirements.txt:

```
Flask==0.8
gevent==0.13.7
gunicorn==0.13.2
```

I've tried different versions of gunicorn from 0.13.7 to 0.14.6 with no success.

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Running this command:

```
heroku logs
```

gives this:

```
←[33m2012-08-09T21:08:02+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ImportError: No module named app.
wsgiapp ←[33m2012-08-09T21:08:02+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     entry = __import__(self.modul
e_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
```

Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried a newer gunicorn version, e.g. 0.14.6 like heroku specify in their example? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python/#using-a-different-wsgi-server

Comment: yes, does not change anything

Comment: That can't be the whole app.py file. Add in the imports from the top.

Comment: for sure it is there, it is stripped for brevity, i mentioned that it works on heroku without gunicorn

Comment: @Joseph what do you mean "stripped for brevity"? The ImportError is probably happening because of a module you're importing that's missing some requirements. Any import statements you have in your script are probably the key to figuring out the issue.

Comment: @Joseph Are you able to run gunicorn locally? If so do you get the same error?

Comment: it run locally perfectly

Comment: @Joseph what did you do to fix this? I'm having the same issue right now. I have no idea why it went from "working" to "not work" with gunicorn.

Comment: Same here, simplest possible config and it was working before I switched over to using a gunicorn config file

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I got this error by having a `gunicorn.py` file in my top level folder. This clashed with the installed gunicorn library on Heroku.

So my run command that caused the problem was:

```
gunicorn -c gunicorn.py myapp:main
```

Raising the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 378, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2566, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2260, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named app.wsgiapp
```

Whereas after a `mv gunicorn.py gunicorn_config.py` it worked fine with:

```
gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py myapp:main
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem when upgrading Ubuntu to 14.04 LTS.

For some reason, `gunicorn` failed to pick up the correct python path to resolve the wsgi module.

I resolved this, for now, by declaring the python path explicitly to `gunicorn` via the `--pythonpath` parameter (documented [here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/develop/configure.html#pythonpath)).

For example:

```
gunicorn --pythonpath /path/to/containing/directory "app.wsgi_app:wsgi_app"
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured this one out.

It's basically just a PATH problem. If you import certain modules (like **os** and **sys**) in the wrong order depending on your setup, you will cause Gunicorn to look in the wrong package for the **app.wsgiapp** module. (not to be confused with the **app.wsgi_app** function in Flask)

The correct import order will vary depending on your setup, but the rule of thumb based on what I was able to get working was to just make sure that your **sys** module is imported before your **os** module.

Beyond that, assuming the rest of the config is normal (as above) you shouldn't have any issues.

Note: THIS IS ONLY A PROBLEM ON HEROKU with Gunicorn. It has something to do with how their PYTHONPATH and module search path is set up. I don't know why exactly, but this is only necessary for the production environment, local setups will work fine regardless of the module import order.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is there is an other "app" module in the python path (both gunicorn and flask have a module called app already).
Rename it anything else than app.py and it should work.

Comment: I do not think so, because when i rename the module to something like another_app i got the same error with the new module name

Comment: Can you log repr(app) an PYTHON_PATH env var before it crashes ?

Comment: How? Gunicorn itself is crashing.... it does not even go to my code... any snippit of code to demonestrate how can i do that?

Comment: Well it tries to access wsiapp which is an existing property of the flask app. So your code must be loaded. Just put something in the body of your module file. Also run gunicorn with --log-level=DEBUG

Comment: This was what I found to be the case, see my answer regarding changing import orders above.