# Gunicorn+Django+Heroku. Python Path Issue

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn, pythonpath

I'm running a Django app that I used to deploy to Heroku with Gunicorn without a hitch. By that I mean that I could run

```
foreman start
```

on my localhost and be able to understand whether the application would work in the production environment. I recently made the decision to move all of our project's applications into a subfolder named 'applications'. This meant editing my DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable among other files. After doing this, I experimented with foreman and gunicorn until I got the local server up and running. At this point I deployed to production. Needless to say, there was an error:

```
Running `gunicorn --workers=4 applications.rocketlistings.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0: -k gevent` attached to terminal... up, run.8052
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==0.17.2', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 343, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2307, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2013, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named app.wsgiapp
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and it's very difficult to debug the situation given the obscure remote setup heroku runs. [Other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13905449/313299) discussing this error suggest that this is a path problem. This sounds very plausible, but I can't think of what could be wrong with the path, given that I have an **init**.py file in my applications folder, and everything works locally.

Here is my production path/pythonpath anyway:

```
Running `echo $PATH` attached to terminal... up, run.2583
/app/.heroku/python/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

Running `echo $PYTHONPATH` attached to terminal... up, run.8026
/app/
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, this occurs when Gunicorn finds another module called 'app' in the PYTHONPATH. Setting PYTHONPATH to a fake value resolves the issue:

```
$ heroku config:set PYTHONPATH=fakepath
```

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/wiki/Troubleshooting#no-module-named-appwsgiapp

Comment: That ended up being the issue. Thanks!